# Should tag wikis include references to other tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, markdown, tag-wiki

Oftentimes when editing a tag wiki I wonder, if it is encouraged to include references to other tags via the `[tag: ...]` markdown syntax.

For example, many rather general tags could benefit from listing subtopics in their wiki to give users a better understanding of the tag's context or potentially encourage them to use the more specific tag where applicable.

As an example of this, see https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/lean-ux/info , where the tag wiki of [lean-ux](/questions/tagged/lean-ux) links to the [agile-development](/questions/tagged/agile-development) tag, because lean ux is a technique that real only came about in the context of agile development.

So my question: **Should tag wikis "interlink" by using other tags? Is this desireable or should it even be avoided?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely!

Using tag links is great for tag wikis, *especially* when used to illustrate the proper use of a tag, or to point to alternatives.

The Stack Overflow [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag wiki uses this to great effect to point version-specific tags, for example:

> ### Tagging recommendation:
>
> It is recommended that you use the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag. If you believe
> your question includes issues specific to the incompatible Python 2.x
> or Python 3.x, use [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) or [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x). If you
> believe your question may be even more specific, you can include a
> version tag such as [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

I'd say that this is the *number one reason* for the existence of the `[tag:tagname]` markup.